# featured images twenty eleven theme

Tags: post-thumbnails, theme-twenty-eleven

Iv'e implemented the theme to have the featured post at the top display as a full post and the rest of the posts below display as excerpts but now my featured images aren't showing up.  Im new to PHP (learning by books)...
can someone show me the code for this?
thanks in adavance
JIM

Comment: first off if your are new to php and want to learn it fast suggest you sign up at lynda.com and watch (jupp video courses, in high quality) the two courses they have on php (essential training and beyond the basics). I also really recommend the Wordpress courses. you can also skip right to the wordpress courses if you just need to build a wordpress theme.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add some of the code from your Loop.php file? The code you need to make a featured image show up is:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );?>
```

If you want the medium size picture to show up, use `thumbnail`, `large` or just `''` (original size) to show other sizes.

Just to be sure, have you chosen a thumbnail picture for each post? **This is not done automatically**, if you don't see a option for this in your post editor you need to activate this feature in your function.php file like this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```